# Continuous Integration of SQL Server in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was just about to do a continuous integration of SQL Server scripts with VSTS. I have two script files in my visual studio 2015 database project.

- `createStudentTable.sql` => simple create table script
- `Script.PostDeployment1.sql` => :r .\createStudentTable.sql (pointing to the above script)

Now after the successful build in visual studio online I suddenly recognized that a `.dacpac` file is also created - see this screenshot:

[image]

Now my database has around 100 tables + view and stored procedures. Now does this `.dacpac` file contain the entire schema details? If so then it would be an huge overhead in carrying this `.dacpac` with every build.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dacpac file only contains the schema model definition of your database and it does not contain any of table data unless you add all of insert statements in the postdeploymentscript.sql

The overhead of dacpac is that it compares the model in dacpac and your target database when the actual deployment happens.

This is a trade-off. If you don't use dacpac then you will end up doing all the database versions and version migrations by yourself manually or using another tool that can make those database change managements with ALTER statements somewhat easier.

BTW the scale of 100 table can be handled well by dacpac.

Comment: So, what do you mean by schema models? Is it like an xml like content with all the schema details with no actual data? In my case the dacpac will containjust the schema information of my 100 tables and view/procedures? Any link would be helpful as well

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications